# Store and Change Session variable - PHP SESSION VARIABLE

Tags: php, variables, session

I would like to change a session variable which will change another variable in two different places. One variable determines what posts the user will see which is in my custom post archive file(archive-spark.php) and the other in my (functions.php) file which I am using in a Gravity forms hook which determines which category the form will post to. The gravity form is a pop up on all pages.

All is working fine when I am on custom post type page(archive-spark.php), the form I created changes the variables in both but when I reload the page or go to another page the default variable I have set loads again. I can see why it does this as I have the session in a 'if(isset)' but I just don't know how to hold the variable as session variable after my form submission.

I am using this plugin for my session variables:
http://silvermapleweb.com/using-the-php-session-in-wordpress/

Here is the code:
archive-spark.php

```
<?php
//this is default variable if nothing is submitted with my form
$the_user_garden = "gardens"; 
?>

<?php
//this is the form that will change the variable
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
$the_user_garden = $_POST['sub_garden_1'];
}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="sub_garden_1" value="sub_garden_1"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>

<?php
//this put the new variable value   from the form as session variable
$_SESSION['myKey'] = $the_user_garden; 
?>

<?php
$author_id = get_current_user_id( );
//this is where I am using the changes variable
if( have_rows($the_user_garden, 'user_'.$author_id) ): ?> 

<?php 
//and here too
while( have_rows($the_user_garden, 'user_'.$author_id) ): the_row(); ?>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');

function myStartSession() {
if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();

}
}

function myEndSession() {
session_destroy ();
}

?>
<?php
// this is where I need the variable for gravity form(pop up)   
 if(isset($_SESSION['myKey'])) {
$the_user_garden = $_SESSION['myKey'];
} else {
$the_user_garden = "gardens";

}
?>

<?php
//this is where I am using variable
$author_id = get_current_user_id( );
if( have_rows($the_user_garden, 'user_'.$author_id) ): ?>
```

Basically I need a way for session variable to be stored through out the website on all pages and if I submit my form for that variable to be held.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if anyone understood my problem but if you did and are having something similar I will post how I figured it out.

I simply had to add a session_start(); on my form..

```
<?php
session_start(); //see here
//this is the form that will change the variable
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
$the_user_garden = $_POST['sub_garden_1'];
}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="sub_garden_1" value="sub_garden_1"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>
```